# How to make the yasnippet as the auto-complete backend?

Tags: emacs, autocomplete, yasnippet

I want to make the `yasnippet` as the backend of the `auto-complete`. However, it doesn't work. what I do after searched the internet is as follows:
get the [auto-complete-yasnippet.el](http://www.cx4a.org/pub/auto-complete-yasnippet.el), add some elisp in the `.emacs` like this:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path
     "~/.emacs.d/plugins/yasnippet")
(require 'yasnippet)
(yas-global-mode 1)
(yas-minor-mode nil)
(global-set-key (kbd "M-/") 'yas/expand)

;; Auto-complete settings
;; this is the code for the auto-complete
(require 'auto-complete-config)
(add-to-list 'ac-dictionary-directories "~/.emacs.d//ac-dict")
(ac-config-default)

;;setup for auto-complete-yasnippet
(require 'auto-complete-yasnippet)
(setq-default ac-sources
      '(
        ;; ac-source-semantic
        ac-source-yasnippet
        ac-source-abbrev
        ac-source-words-in-buffer
        ac-source-words-in-all-buffer
        ;; ac-source-imenu
        ac-source-files-in-current-dir
        ac-source-filename
        )
      )
```

I look at the content in the `ac-sources` in *scratch* with <kbd>C-h v</kbd>, and it does have the `ac-source-yasnippet`. someone [said](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AutoComplete) that there may be something wrong with the version and upgrade of `auto-complete` as well as `yasnippet`. How can it be fixed? 
My `emacs` version is 23.3.1 my `auto-complete` version is 1.3.1 and my `yasnippet` version is 0.8.0(beta) which is just downloaded from the [github](https://github.com/capitaomorte/yasnippet). any help?

Comment: I am using the emacs under Windows 7, and the `M-/` is the keybinding that I defined to make `yasnippet` do not conflict with `auto-complete` when using the key <kbd>TAB</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

you can easily do it by `(require 'auto-complete-yasnippet)`

and then you can change your auto-complete like follows:

```
(defun my-ac-config ()
  (setq-default ac-sources '(ac-source-abbrev ac-source-dictionary ac-source-words-in-same-mode-buffers))
  (add-hook 'emacs-lisp-mode-hook 'ac-emacs-lisp-mode-setup)
  ;; (add-hook 'c-mode-common-hook 'ac-cc-mode-setup)
  (add-hook 'ruby-mode-hook 'ac-ruby-mode-setup)
  (add-hook 'css-mode-hook 'ac-css-mode-setup)
  (add-hook 'auto-complete-mode-hook 'ac-common-setup)
  (add-hook 'octave-mode-hook 'ac-octave-mode-setup)
  (global-auto-complete-mode t))
(defun my-ac-cc-mode-setup ()
  (setq ac-sources (append '(ac-source-clang ac-source-yasnippet) ac-sources)))
(add-hook 'c-mode-common-hook 'my-ac-cc-mode-setup)
;; ac-source-gtags
(my-ac-config)
```

It works fine on my machine.

Comment: I think it may the problem of the `yasnippet` version, see my answer downside.

Answer (score 2):

there maybe something wrong with the `auto-complete-config.el` when acquire the `ac-yasnippet-candidates` in the `auto-complete-1.3.1` version:

```elisp
(defun ac-yasnippet-candidates ()
  (with-no-warnings
    (if (fboundp 'yas/get-snippet-tables)
        ;; >0.6.0
        (apply 'append (mapcar 'ac-yasnippet-candidate-1 (yas/get-snippet-tables major-mode)))
      (let ((table
             (if (fboundp 'yas/snippet-table)
                 ;; <0.6.0
                 (yas/snippet-table major-mode)
               ;; 0.6.0
               (yas/current-snippet-table))))
        (if table
            (ac-yasnippet-candidate-1 table))))))
```

the code snippet above somewhat must be changed to be compatible with the `yasnippet-0.8.0`version. I download the newest version of `auto-complete-1.4.0` from [github](https://github.com/m2ym/auto-complete) and it solved the problem judge the version of `yasnippet` and take measures accordingly. Like this:

```elisp
(defun ac-yasnippet-candidates ()
  (with-no-warnings
    (cond (;; 0.8 onwards
           (fboundp 'yas-active-keys)
           (all-completions ac-prefix (yas-active-keys)))
          (;; >0.6.0
           (fboundp 'yas/get-snippet-tables)
           (apply 'append (mapcar 'ac-yasnippet-candidate-1
                                  (condition-case nil
                                      (yas/get-snippet-tables major-mode)
                                    (wrong-number-of-arguments
                                     (yas/get-snippet-tables))))))
          (t
           (let ((table
                  (if (fboundp 'yas/snippet-table)
                      ;; <0.6.0
                      (yas/snippet-table major-mode)
                    ;; 0.6.0
                    (yas/current-snippet-table))))
             (if table
                 (ac-yasnippet-candidate-1 table)))))))
```

I copied the `auto-complete-config.el` from the `auto-complete-1.4.0`version, byte compiled it, and replaced the same files(both `auto-complete-config.el` and `auto-complete-config.elc`) in `auto-complete-1.3.1`version. it just worked! I think may the config file of `auto-complete` should not included in the distro and maybe it should maintained separately to make it easy to compatible with its backends.

I reconfigured the `yasnippet` and the `auto-complete` like this:

```elisp
;; setup for yasnippet
(add-to-list 'load-path
      "~/.emacs.d/plugins/yasnippet")
;; Extension and configuration of yasnippet.
(require 'yasnippet-config)
;; If you use yasnippet from 'auto-complete', add
(yas/set-ac-modes)
(yas/enable-emacs-lisp-paren-hack)
;; before 'auto-complete' settings.
;; Auto-complete settings
;; this is the code for the auto-complete
(require 'auto-complete-config)
(add-to-list 'ac-dictionary-directories "~/.emacs.d//ac-dict")
(ac-config-default)
```